# Jenkins and Jira Integration

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jira

Hi I will try to integrate jenkins and jira, but I will not use a jira plugin for jenkins I need to do this integration with groovy.

But when I try to execute a groovy script in a myhost/jenkins/script or in a build step "Execute System Groovy Script" I get the same error:

"FATAL: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/namespace/QName"
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/namespace/QName"

My code is simple:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.client.*
def serviceLocator = new JiraSoapServiceServiceLocator()
```

The error is because there is more than one jar with the same class in the classpath of the JVM Jenkins? But how to know which jar? Can I change the classpath to remove this jar?

Comment: start by looking for jar files containing the QName class

Comment: @drob is xpp3-1.1.4c.jar and stax-api-1.0.1.jar, how can I remove from jenkins classpath one of this jars?

Comment: I would replace xpp3-1.1.4c.jar with xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar which does not contain the QName class